# Doctrine2...Best hydration mode?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am designing a room booking system which has nine entities, which all relate to each other. In this specific instance I am retrieving 10-30 rows from the entity `entry` which has 25 properties. Each entry has one `room` which has 10 properties. I need all of the entry information as well as `entry->room->id` and `entry->room->name`. But it seems like doctrine is loading the entire `room` when I use `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`. It seems to be lazy-loading in `Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT` more easily.

So, I am wondering if using the `Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT` mode is faster or "better" than `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` / `Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR`/ `Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR`. Since I am reusing some older code I'd like to use `HYDRATE_ARRAY` but only if it won't slow the application down.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My 2 cents:

`HYDRATE_OBJECT` is best for when you plan on using a lot of business logic with your objects. Especially if you're doing a lot of data manipulation. It's also probably the slowest (depending on the situation).

`HYDRATE_ARRAY` is usually reserved for when you only need a result and 1 degrees of relational data and it's going to be used for printing/viewing purposes only.

`HYDRATE_NONE` is another one I use when I'm only selecting a very small subset of data (like one or two fields instead of the entire row). This behaves much like a raw query result would.

This might also be of interest http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/17/doctrine-performance-revisited.html

This is from the 1.2 docs but I think the Hydration tips apply in 2.0 http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/improving-performance.html

> Another important rule that belongs in this category is: Only fetch objects when you really need them. Doctrine has the ability to fetch "array graphs" instead of object graphs. At first glance this may sound strange because why use an object-relational mapper in the first place then? Take a second to think about it. PHP is by nature a precedural language that has been enhanced with a lot of features for decent OOP. Arrays are still the most efficient data structures you can use in PHP. Objects have the most value when they're used to accomplish complex business logic. It's a waste of resources when data gets wrapped in costly object structures when you have no benefit of that

On using `HYDRATE_ARRAY`:

> Can you think of any benefit of having objects in the view instead of arrays? You're not going to execute business logic in the view, are you? One parameter can save you a lot of unnecessary processing:

```
$blogPosts = $q->execute(array(1), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Just a note. `HYDRATE NONE` doesn't seem to exist...is this from 1.2? I'm using `HYDRATE_SCALAR` and `HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR` instead.

Comment: @Daniel You're probably right. I've only used 1.2 but the `SCALAR` methods appear to yield the same benefits as `HYDRATE_NONE`.

Comment: um, can you tell me the fullpath to the file that defines Doctrine_Core? I think my install of symfony2 is wonky.

Comment: @OwenBeresford Be careful, my answer was referring to Doctrine 1.2. Symfony 2 *most likely* uses Doctrine 2. The hydration constants appear to be part of the Query class in Doctrine 2 http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: What is that first parameter **array(1)** in `execute(array(1), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`?

Comment: @Čamo Look at the API http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.AbstractQuery.html#_execute

Comment: By September 2021 each and every link to Doctrine's documentation is broken (no doubt they were active at the time they were quoted). Plus, googling the words `doctrine query execute hydrate` gives as 1st result a link to a [page](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/manual/data-hydrators.html) that states "This project is no longer maintained and has been archived.". One must have a lot of nerve to use such library in any serious project...

Comment: Your link refer to Doctrine 1 which is no longer maintained. Doctrine is on version 2 today and will release soon version 3. Here's the link for [hydration mode](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes)