# Doctrine memory error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

On my web application with Doctrine, I am suddenly getting an error as below:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in {path_to_doctrine}/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php on line 53

I didn't show up before. Also, FYI, the section facing this issue has several thousands of data rows and do have relationship with other entities. I just can't understand what memory problem it might be.

Another interesting thing is, the error isn't throwing from 'DateTimeType.php' always, somethings I did get it on 'UnitOfwork.php' and some other files as well.

Can somebody help me what I can do to resolve this error please?

My environment is:
Ubuntu, Amazon EC2 micro instance, RDS database server, PHP 5.3.

```
Code For data retrieval:
/**
     * Return list of recors according to given start index and length
     * @param type $start the start index number for the city list
     * @param type $length Determines how many records to fetch
     * @return type 
     */
    function get_by_range($start=1,$length=10,$criteria = array(),$orderBy = NULL)
    {
        try
        {
            return $this->em->getRepository($this->entity)->findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $length, $start);
        }
        catch(Exception $err)
        {
            log_message("error", $err->getMessage(), false);
            print_r($err->getMessage());exit();
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

it is being called to fill the main list:

```
$this->data["joblist"]            =   $this->jobmodel->get_by_range((($page-1)*$pagingConfig['per_page']),$pagingConfig['per_page'],array("site"=>  "test"), array('postTime' => 'DESC'));
```

Entity class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PdJobs
 *
 * @Table(name="pd_jobs")
 * @Entity
 */
class PdJobs
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $projectId
     *
     * @Column(name="project_id", type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $projectId;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string $url
     *
     * @Column(name="url", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string $shortDescription
     *
     * @Column(name="short_description", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $shortDescription;

    /**
     * @var string $site
     *
     * @Column(name="site", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $site;

    /**
     * @var datetime $postTime
     *
     * @Column(name="post_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $postTime;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="PdExpertises", inversedBy="jobs", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     * @JoinTable(name="pd_jobs_expertises")
     */
    private $expertises;

    /**
     * @var string $type
     *
     * @Column(name="type", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @Column(name="description", type="string", length=1000, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string $budget
     *
     * @Column(name="budget", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $budget;

    /**
     * @var string $skill
     *
     * @Column(name="skill", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $skill;

    /**
     * @var integer $candidates
     *
     * @Column(name="candidates", type="integer", options={"default":0},nullable=true)
     */
    private $candidates;

    /**
     * @var string $averageAmount
     *
     * @Column(name="average_amount", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $averageAmount;

    /**
     * @var datetime $startDate
     *
     * @Column(name="start_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var datetime $endDate
     *
     * @Column(name="end_date", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @var string $category
     *
     * @Column(name="category", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;/**
     * @var string $subCategory
     *
     * @Column(name="sub_category", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $subCategory;

    /**
     * @var string $clientCountry
     *
     * @Column(name="client_country", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $clientCountry;

    /**
     * @var string $clientRating
     *
     * @Column(name="client_rating", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $clientRating;
```

per page max of 25 rows are retrieved. So I was thinking may be its not a issue? Also I have "fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" in case of foreign key relationship. So, I hope that part is safe too?

However, I was thinking another point, my primary key column 'id' is of type 'integer' , is it could be the problem? However, error doesn't point to this error specifically. Also, just to clarify, I have around 30k data in total.

Comment: How many rows are you retrieving in one go? Can we see the relevant block of code?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the query that retrieves the records. How are you hydrating the results set? If you don't need the results as objects, you can hydrate them as an array (see this [SO answer]: [Doctrine2...Best hydration mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794619/doctrine2-best-hydration-mode)

If you don't need the results all at once, you can retrieve and process them sequentially.

There is also an option of "EXTRA LAZY LOADING" in Doctrine (since version 2.1), described in the [manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) manual as:

> In many cases associations between entities can get pretty large. Even in a simple scenario like a blog. where posts can be commented, you always have to assume that a post draws hundrets of comments. In Doctrine 2.0 if you accessed an association it would always get loaded completly into memory. This can lead to pretty serious performance problems, if your associations contain several hundrets or thousands of entities.

If you are trying to output the query result (ie var_dump, print_r), the memory will be exhausted even on much smaller datasets.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the main question description, hope those gives some of your answers. Yes, I am using 'extra lazy loading' on association. Also, retrieval are being done via range as you can see above. That's why I am more confused about what might be wrong.

Comment: Is it possible to see the entity class?

Comment: ok, sure. Just edited the question description with the entity class code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm out of constructive ideas. However, try using DQL with joins instead of getRepository to fetch the records, as the getRepository method is really convenient, but DQL gives you more control. Also, in the doctrine manual it says about extra lazy associations that there are several methods available for use with this fetch mode in order to avoid triggering the full load of the collection. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: no problem. Thanks for looking into and also thanks for the suggestions. I will try the alternatives and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Do post what you discover, as it is interesting and will probably be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about several thousands of data rows, it can well be, that you (in the past view days/months) were exactly below this limit and now, that time went on and the data was growing, it reached the limit.

Is there a way to reduce the data you need at that time in PHP? Don't know if you really need all those thousands of rows at that time ... Doctrine is capable of stuff like lazy-loading - loading the data just if needed - to keep the memory-footprint as low as possible.

If you think about exceeding the memory-limit, make sure it's big enough to manage the incoming data for, at least, the next months. Drupal pointed out some ways to exceed this value even if you don't have access to the php.ini file: http://drupal.org/node/207036

I think you should review your code and discuss it with an doctrine expert, or post it here, so an expert can help you out.